# What is the value in matplotlib.pyplot in the upper left angle for almost equal values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some dataset:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = [28892147.7659855, 28892150.0913124, 28892148.7255983, 28892146.365328,
          28892148.101613, 28892147.0887403, 28892147.8564253, 28892146.8626385,
          28892146.480244, 28892146.8724146, 28892146.699191, 28892146.405013,
          28892146.225238, 28892146.434353, 28892146.3250017, 28892146.344571,
          28892146.494564, 28892146.36454, 28892146.8347917, 28892146.20861,
          28892146.222876]

plt.plot(dataset)
```

[image]

by what logic `matplotlib.pyplot` outputs the value of `2.8892100000e7`?

Comment: Taking this number (`2.8892100000e7`) and adding it to the value that you can read from the datapoints and you get the value you inputed. That means that `2.8892100000e7` is just there to keep the numbers on the left as low as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the [`ScalarFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter) that is used to set the tick mark labels, will work out an offset value to try and make the tick labels ["round" numbers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/auto_ticks.html). How the offset is worked out can be found in the [`_compute_offset`  method here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.6.2/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L720). How to turn off the offset is shown in the examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/scalarformatter.html). One way being, e.g.,

```
plt.plot(dataset)

# get axes object
ax = plt.gca()

# turn off the offset
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```